# create table with time datatype and insertion time data in table

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, type-conversion

I want to insert a time data in a table . So, what type of datatypes, I should use and how can I insert a time in a table? I used 'timestamp' in create table statement, but when I insert a time in table, it shows an error (error-code : ORA-01861). Please help me.  I use ORACLE 11g.

DDL statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE "SOM"."FLIGHTS" 
   (    "FLNO" NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FROM" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "DISTANCE" NUMBER(5,3), 
    "DEPARTS" TIMESTAMP (3), 
    "ARRIVES" TIMESTAMP (3), 
    "PRICE" NUMBER(5,2), 
     CONSTRAINT "FLIGHTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("FLNO")   );
```

insert statement:

```
insert into flights 
values (1, 'Bbsr', 'Calcutta', 600, timestamp '05:30', timestamp '06:50', 8000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message for ORA-01861 is `literal does not match format string`.  This error means we're casting a string to another data type but the string has the wrong format.

Your insert statement features two casts of a string to a TIMESTAMP datatype using the ANSI SQL style `timestamp()` function.  This function takes prescribed formats: `YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS`, `YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF` and `YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF TZ`.

You are getting ORA-01861 because your string does not match one of those formats: `timestamp '05:30'`.

In this case the solution is to change the column datatype: you do not want a timestamp, which is a specific time on a specific date.  What you want is just the flight's take-off and landing  times, which would be better expressed as `number(4,2)` or `varchar2(5)` which a check constraint.

---

Two other observations.

Your insert statement has numeric value which are too big for the specified number columns, which is easy to fix.

Your table definition uses oracle reserved words as column names,  TO and FROM.  The create statement succeeds only because you have wrapped everything in double quotes, so Oracle doesn't validate the names.  Using reserved words like this is *incredibly bad practice*.  Every time we refer to the columns we will need to write ...

```
  select  flno, "FROM", "TO" from flights;
```

... otherwise the we'll get ORA-00936 ([SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9f8b/20)).  The poor saps who have to use your table and maintain your code will curse you forever.  Don't be that guy.